# Parse Error on if statement in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, if-statement

This is for an academic assignment and I simply cannot fix it.

I have a list (database) of "tracks" (of music records) - tuples of (Title, Artist, SalesNumber) and my task is to increment a sale of a given track if it is already present in the database (same title and artist) and just increment by 1 to sales number, or if is not already present, to add it to the database. I have written - I think correctly - functions to perform either of these tasks however am struggling to write the function which determines whether adding a new record or simply incrementing it and to call either.

```
addNewTrack :: [Sale] -> Title -> Artist -> [Sale]
addNewTrack testDatabase title artist = testDatabase

incrExistingTrack :: [Sale] -> Title -> Artist -> [Sale]
incrExistingTrack testDatabase testedTitle testedArtist = []
incrExistingTrack ((title, artist, salesNumber): xs) testedTitle    testedArtist
 | testedTitle == title && testedArtist == artist =
 [(title, artist, salesNumber + 1)]
 | otherwise = incrExistingTrack xs title artist

recordSale :: [Sale] -> Title -> Artist -> [Sale]
recordSale testDatabase title artist
let trackExists = sameTrack title artist
if trackExists == True
 then incrExistingTrack title artist
 else addNewTrack title artist

sameTrack :: Title -> Artist -> Sale -> Bool
sameTrack queriedTitle queriedArtist (title, artist, salesNumber)
 | (queriedTitle == title) && (queriedArtist == artist) = True
 | otherwise = False
```

What is wrong with the if statement in my recordSale function to give "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" on the first character of the fourth line of the function?

```
recordSale :: [Sale] -> Title -> Artist -> [Sale]
recordSale testDatabase title artist
let trackExists = sameTrack title artist
if trackExists == True
  then incrExistingTrack title artist
  else addNewTrack title artist
```

I have been shifting things around and changing indents to no avail. I am sure it must be a very simple error. How can I identify the problem? Is there an alternative and possibly more elegant implementation of what I'm trying to do?

```
recordSale :: [Sale] -> Title -> Artist -> [Sale]
recordSale testDatabase title artist
  = let trackExists = sameTrack title artist
    in if trackExists == True
        then incrExistingTrack testDatabase title artist
        else addNewTrack testDatabase title artist
```

Comment: Your `let` syntax looks off. You need an `in` in there don't you?

Comment: Hi there, cheers for quick reply, I have no idea on this! what does that do?

Comment: [This](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where) would be a good read over.

Comment: Thanks for that again, implemented the series of in then else statements (see latest code segment), must be almost sorted as no parse errors but get "couldn't match expected type Sale -> Bool with actual type "Bool", error occurs at "True". Is this simple to fix from here? im far too tired to work anything else out!

Comment: Saying "wrong type from what expected in second argument of ==" I don't understand that, its not an argument is it?

Comment: `addNewTrack` doesn't do anything except return its first argument. `incrExistingTrack` doesn't do anything except return an empty list, because the first definition consists solely of irrefutable patterns, so it will *always* match any arguments.

Comment: Your `database` is a list of `Sale`s?

Comment: yes, thats absolutely correct.

Comment: When compiling I am also getting told my pattern match is "redundant" in incrExistingTrack, no idea why or how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks for help to all of you who contributed, made the proposed changes and something compiles, but was unable to prove this functionality all worked. I couldn't work out how to output the updated list from addNewTrack rather than simply the same as the first argument, it must be a very simple fix though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fed `sameTrack` too few arguments. It should be `sameTrack testDatabase title artist`.

Also note that `trackExists == True` is verbose. It can be just `trackExists`.